# Um programa que toda vez que for chamado atualiza a hora e o retorno

Tags: python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

Boa noite estou tentando fazer um programa que testa se a internet está funcionando e se não estiver retorna a hora que vai ser armazenada em um arquivo pra eu poder reclamar junto a operadora da internet.
Sendo que sempre que eu inicio essa programa o retorno é sempre o mesmo

```
from conexao import Programa
from datetime import datetime
import time

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'
hora = Programa.hora()
conexao = Programa.conectar(url, hora)

while True:
    print(conexao)
    conexao
```

---

```
import requests
import time
from datetime import datetime
class Programa():
    def conectar(url, hora):
        while True:
            try:
                requests.get(url, timeout=5)
                time.sleep(5)
                return 1, hora
            except :
                requests.get('http://10.0.0.1/index.asp', timeout=5)
                return 2, hora
            else:
                return 3, hora

    def desconto(valor_minuto, hora):
        desconto = (int(hora) - int(hora) / 60) - valor_minuto
        return desconto

    def hora():
        hora = datetime.now().hour
        minuto = datetime.now().minute
        segundo = datetime.now().second
        hora_caiu = (f'{hora}:{minuto}:{segundo}')
        return hora_caiu
```

Answer (score 1):

O retorno da sua função é sempre o mesmo porque você não atualiza a `hora` e nem testa novamente a conexão, você está apenas imprimindo várias e várias vezes o resultado da chamada de um único teste de conexão feito. Fora que o bloco *while* que você definiu dentro do método `conexao`, é inútil, pois ao retornar um valor, o programa saiu do método e consequentemente ele sai do bloco *while*.

Para corrigir este problema, você pode retirar o *while* de dentro do seu método e pode chamar `Programa.hora()` e `Programa.conectar(url, hora)` dentro do bloco de repetição *while*, dessa forma:

```
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'

while True:
    hora = Programa.hora()                  # Obtém a hora do computador
    conexao = Programa.conectar(url, hora)  # Realiza um novo teste de conexão
    print(conexao)                          # Imprime resultado do novo teste
```

Há também alguns lugares no seu código que também podem ser melhorados, por exemplo, se você deseja obter uma hora formata, você pode utilizar este código:

```
hora = time.localtime()                 # Obtém data e hora do seu computador.
hora = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", hora)  # Formata em "Hora:Minuto:Segundo"
```

Eu não sei se você sabe disso, mas se você alguma hora desejar criar um objeto de `Programa`, o seu código pode dar erro, pois você não definiu na assinatura dos métodos, o parâmetro `self`, que é um parâmetro que recebe uma instância.

Se não foi proposital, que tal declarar acima do método o decorador `@staticmethod` ? Eu sei que por enquanto esse é um assunto um pouco mais complexo para você, mas é bom avisar.

```
class Programa():

    @staticmethod
    def conectar(url, hora):
        try:
            requests.get(url, timeout=5)
            time.sleep(5)
            return 1, hora
        except:
            requests.get('http://10.0.0.1/index.asp', timeout=5)
            return 2, hora
        else:
            return 3, hora

    @staticmethod
    def obterHora():
        hora = time.localtime()                 
        hora = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", hora)
        return hora
```

Eu também não acho uma boa ideia você criar uma classe somente para esse tipo de coisa, o seu código ficaria muito melhor dentro de funções.

Para entender mais sobre *Programação Orientada a Objeto em Python*, clique [aqui](https://panda.ime.usp.br/pensepy/static/pensepy/13-Classes/classesintro.html).